# how to count empty space in c

Tags: c, input, count

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 30
int main()
{
    char string1[SIZE];

    printf("%s","Enter a string less than 29 characters");
    scanf("%s",string1);
    int countword=0;
    int countvowel=0;
    int countspace=0;
    int numberofcons;

    for(size_t i=0;i<SIZE;++i){
        if(string1[i]==' '){
            countspace++;
            countword++;
            printf("h");
        }
        if(string1[i]=='a'||string1[i]=='A'||string1[i]=='e'||string1[i]=='E'||string1[i]=='i'||string1[i]=='I'||string1[i]=='o'||string1[i]=='O'||string1[i]=='u'||string1[i]=='U'){
            countvowel=countvowel+1;
            printf("h");
        }
    }
    numberofcons=SIZE-countvowel-countspace;
    printf("Your sentence include\n");
    printf("Number of words:");
    printf("%d\n",countword);
    printf("Number of spaces:");
    printf("%d\n",countspace);
    printf("Number of vowels:");
    printf("%d\n",countvowel);
    printf("Number of consonants and special characters:");
    printf("%d\n",numberofcons);
    printf("%s",string1);
}
```

so this is my program but somehow it does not run properly. the result shows every count i write is still 0 and I found the input string1 only reads til the first space how can I fix it

Comment: Use fgets instead of scanf.

Comment: If you want to continue to use `scanf` then carefully read the [scanf man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf). In particular the section describing `%s`:
"Matches a sequence of **non-white-space characters**; the next pointer must be a pointer to character array that is long enough to hold the input sequence and the terminating null byte ('\0'), which is added automatically. The **input string stops at white space** or at the maximum field width, whichever occurs first."

Comment: Trick to replace that long set of `||`'s looking for a vowel: `if (strchr("aeiouAEIOU", string1[i])) { /* stuff */ }`

Comment: One of the simplest debugging techniques is to print the data a program reads so you can see whether the program sees the data you expect it to see.

Comment: Your code only reads the string up to the first space. use gets(char[]) instead of scanf().
Also, the increment word count once before printing.

Comment: thank you guys alot, I figured out that I should use the %[^\n]specifier for scanf to read anything

Comment: "I figured out that I should use the %[^\n]specifier for scanf to read anything" --> No use `fgets()`.

Comment: Whatever you do, this code is extremely fragile until you (a) limit the input size with a field width specifier (e.g. `%29s` or `%29[^\n]`) and (b) examine the value returned by `scanf()`.